# Paypal Plus - How to get user selected payment method (decrypted)

Tags: javascript, encryption, paypal

In my form I implemented the PayPal Plus paywall which is documented here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf.

Everything works well so far, but after users payment selection I want to show an order summary on next page and need the user selected payment method, which is stored encrypted in paypalplus_session_v2 cookie.

I also can call the getPaymentMethod() which will return the same encrypted string like this:

```
paymentMethod "pp-82c59049fcdc48ec960990a83b100cb7"
```

So, how to get plaintext payment method?

Here is some JS code for better explanation:

```
var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
    "approvalUrl": appUrl,
    "placeholder": "ppplus",
    "mode": "sandbox",
    "country": "DE",
    "language": "de_DE",
    "showPuiOnSandbox": "true",
     buttonLocation: "outside",
     enableContinue: "continueButton",
    "showLoadingIndicator": true,
     onContinue: function () {
         window.location = "nextpage.php";
     },
});

console.log(ppp.getPaymentMethod());
```

... will return paymentMethod "pp-82c59049fcdc48ec960990a83b100cb7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal seems to have recognized the issue and has released a new API (February 2019) which allows you to choose the payment method yourself. This solved my problem.

For further informations and a demo, please follow the link!

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#try-the-buttons

Answer (score 4):

**EDITED**

PPPLUS Js sets the options into cookie data like below, and you'll not able to decrypt this `paymentmethod` value without knowing the key,

```
INTERNAL-LOG: saveInCookie data from cookie:    
{
  "mode": "sandbox",
  "useraction": "continue",
  "language": "en_US",
  "country": "DE",
  "ecToken": "EC-0KL610776H817283B",
  "thirdPartyMethods": {},
  "paymentMethod": "pp-ca7aac1ecc8fb208ad8b0e3020fc290a"
}
```

Seems the `paymentMethod` values are not for public use at this moment, but if you could load the iframe DOM objects you'll be able to get the `data-pm` attributes and create a map for the native `paymentMethod` names (PayPal, Bank, Credit_Card) in this case.

Check for the following tags in the iframe:

```
<div class="paymentMethodRow row "id="pp&#x2D;f029166c6c171d6ea4b98d60814e7206" data-pm="PayPal">

<div class="paymentMethodRow row selected"id="pp&#x2D;ca7aac1ecc8fb208ad8b0e3020fc290a" data-pm="Bank">

<div class="paymentMethodRow row "id="pp&#x2D;d5fc25f73191ac7ea7399fc5d43b802d" data-pm="Credit_Card">
```

Comment: Any hints how to get the content of the iframe? It's from another domain, so it's protected.

Comment: @Werner There actually no way to do this. After a phone call with the paypal support, he confirmed that it was not desired to read the data of the iframe. You should inform the customer that the payment is made via Paypal, even if the customer pays with credit card or similar.